# Firemonkey TListView Delete Last Item on List Item Swipe Crash

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, tlistview

I am using dephi firemonkey on Rad Studio 10.3.2 testing on android 9

I Want to Delete the last Item From a TListView. But Before I delete it I Want to ask a confirmation, then delete.

for that I built the sample code below, it has 1 TListview, 2 Speedbuttons, 1 rectangle and 1 label.

the rectangle is visible false, so when the user swipe the listviewitem it will show the delete button. in the delete button i will cancel delete and put the rectangle visible whith the question, if click yes then delete the item. the problem is that the listviewitem delete button never go away and when the user clicks the screen again the app crash.

the following images illustrate the operation

[Before swipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9Nr0.jpg)

[After swipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MNN9.jpg)

[after click delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUkuz.jpg)

[after click yes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXIoH.jpg)

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.ListView.Types, FMX.ListView.Appearances, FMX.ListView.Adapters.Base,
  FMX.ListView, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.Objects;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ListView1: TListView;
    Rectangle1: TRectangle;
    SpeedButton1: TSpeedButton;
    SpeedButton2: TSpeedButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ListView1DeletingItem(Sender: TObject; AIndex: Integer;
      var ACanDelete: Boolean);
    procedure SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure SpeedButton2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  ItemDelete  : Integer;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Item: TListViewItem;
begin
  Item := ListView1.Items.Add();
  Item.Text := 'Item 1';
  Item := ListView1.Items.Add();
  Item.Text := 'Item 2';
  Item := ListView1.Items.Add();
  Item.Text := 'Item 3';
  Item := ListView1.Items.Add();
  Item.Text := 'Item 4';
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1DeletingItem(Sender: TObject; AIndex: Integer; var ACanDelete: Boolean);
begin
  ACanDelete := false;
  ItemDelete := AIndex;
  Rectangle1.Visible := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ItemDelete := -1;
  Rectangle1.Visible := false;
end;

procedure TForm1.SpeedButton2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListView1.Items.Delete(ItemDelete);
  ItemDelete := -1;
  Rectangle1.Visible := false;
end;

end.
```

Comment: If I ignore swiping and click SpeedButton2, `ItemDelete` has been initialised by the compiler to zero, so the first item (Item 1) in the list is deleted without `ListView1DeletingItem` being called, and I get no AV.

Comment: Regardless of where the issue is, do you really need 3 steps (swipe, click Delete, click Yes) to complete the destructive action? Another point is that Yes/No [aren't proper option names](https://material.io/components/dialogs/#alert-dialog) in such a dialog.

Comment: The code above is just a sample to ilustrate. In my actual app the code has a lot more of caution. Yes, i need the confirmation before delete. My problem is when I delete the item. I believe that the problem is After click delete  the item should go back to the original form, before swipe, but it doesnt.

Comment: @AndreNogueira : it is a bit late, and only partially related to your problem regarding the AV with the Delete Button . Using Delphi 10.4.2 on Android. I have an array where I keep data. And I have a procedure which then Fills the Listview based on this array. And then sets the Listview.ItemIndex to ItemCount. This works fine if adding items. But the moment I delete the last item I get an access violation which after debugging leads to the Delete Swipe Button itself. What I did is I set the index when deleting inside onDeleteChangeVisible , otherwise inside onItemChange. No AVs.

Comment: thank you for your help, but now the company where i work stopped using delphi for mobile. we moved to flutter.and i have to say, it was a much better experience. now delphi on mobile last only on legacy apps until i code on flutter

Comment: Btw, no answer from embarcadero yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing this wrong.

The purpose of [ListView OnDeletingItem event](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FMX.ListView.TListViewBase.OnDeletingItem) is to controll whether the deletion of ListView item can occur or not. This should be done within the execution time of that event preferably by showing a modal dialog for confirmation within that event.

But in your code you return `ACanDelete` as false and therefore notifying ListView that it can't delete that item. Later on you try to do deletion of specific ListView item from your own code with a speed button in that rectangle of yours. The problem is that by the time users clicks on any of those speed buttons the contents of ListView might have already changed since as soon as you exited OnDeletinItem event your application resumed with normal execution.

So I strongly recommend that instead of using your rectangle with buttons you use modal dialog for getting confirmation from your user since by using modal dialog you ensure that until modal dialog isn't closed rest of code progression is halted and thus contents of ListView can't change till then.

Documentation on [ListView OnDeletingItem event](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FMX.ListView.TListViewBase.OnDeletingItem) also provides a small code example of hot to show such modal dialog in such scenario so you should definitely check it out.

---

**EDIT:** After spending many hours studying this problem I managed to track the cause of it but unfortunately I don't know how to solve it easily.

First part of the problem is that Android does not support true modal dialogs. So you need to implement additional confirmation to your user synchronously either by using synchronous dialog or by using some custom way as you tried.

But now here we arrive to the second part of the problem which is poor design of TListView component on Embarcadero part.

You see when you use swipe gesture to show the delete button that delete button is not created as part of specific item but as part of the TListViewBase class class from which TListView is eventually derived from. Also a filed called `FDeleteButtonIndex` is set with the index number of a item on which the swipe gesture was performed. Because this Delete button is declared and created so deeply within the TListViewBase class it is not possible to access it directly as it is marked as private.

Now when you click on that Delete button a special event method `DeleteButtonClicked` is executed and in this method the Delete button is destroyed and `FDeleteButtonIndex` is set to -1.

But when you delete ListView item from code Delete button does not get destroyed nor does the `FDeleteButtonIndex` field gets set to -1. Meaning that if you click on that Delete button the second time TListView will go and delete item with the same index as the one before. And if you previously deleted last item you will now get access violation for trying to access the item that is out of bods of your ListView.

So I'm afraid that I don't have any easy solution for you. You could try:

- Create your own custom class for `TListView` as a way to make needed methods public but you will have to make 5 custom since `TListVievBase` is five levels deep in comparison to `TListView`.

  - You could try to use some TRL hacks to access private methods of `TListViewBase` class
  - You could disable default `SwipeToDelete` functionality and implement your own with which you will create your own Delete button at run-time in a way that it is part of the ListItem and therefore gets destroyed with ListItem
  - Or you could request Embarcadero to fix `TListView` so that it either always check to see if Delete button is present for that specific item you are deleting programatically or add another method to `TListView` that would allow us to remove that Delete button whenever we want.

Sorry I can't be of better help

Comment: Yes, previously before rad studio 10.3 I had a dialog inside the delete button. But from 10.3 the dialog sample from embarcadero stopped working and that was my solution. Do you have any other ideia ? Or a sample of question dialog that works on 10.3.2 ?

Comment: I have edited my original answer with some additional information but I'm afraid I don't have a simple solution to you.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, you gave me enought options, i think i will try contact embarcadero on that. For now i got a work around, its not beautiful but it works and gives me more time. In my lists I add a blank item on bottom and disable the code onclick / ondelete of that item.  The result is a blank item at the bottom, the user cant do anything with it, so they can never delete the last item.